# Does HDFS Disk Usage reflect usage of local hard drive space on my PC?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, virtual-machine, diskspace

I run Hortonworks Hadoop in virtualbox and when I went to the Ambari dashboard it shows that the HDFS Disk Usage is at 46% (19.4GB used out of 42GB available). I am curious are these 42GB that I allocated to Hortonworks Sandbox taken from my PC's local hard drive?

I was confused because when I look at the storage allocation of my PC (see screenshot below), the most was "System & reserve" and that only makes up 36GB which is less than the 42GB that I allocated to Hortonworks Sandbox. So could anyone tell me: 1) Is the 42GB I allocated to Hortonworks Sandbox taken from my local hard drive? 2) Where is this 42GB being reflected on the storage usage screenshot that I attached below? 3) Ambari shown that HDFS used 19.4GB. How can I find out where these 19.4GB are being allocated to?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A VirtualBox hard drive has a specific maximum size on the host machine that it reports to the VM, but it is compressed, otherwise to save space on the host

Comment: Thanks, @cricket_007. Is there a way to check where these 19.4GB are being allocated to (i.e. on what data node)?

Comment: It's not on a datanode. It's the OS of the VM (which includes the NameNode, DataNode, and other parts of the HDP VM like Spark, HBase, Hive, etc)